# npm fails to install fibers "Build succeeded but target not found", weird error 1

Tags: macos, node.js, npm, node-fibers

I recently updated node.js on my Mac OSX 10.8.5 by uninstalling my old version and reinstalling through Homebrew. I am now getting errors installing fibers.

npm version gives me:

```
{ http_parser: '1.0',
  node: '0.10.20',
  v8: '3.14.5.9',
  ares: '1.9.0-DEV',
  uv: '0.10.17',
  zlib: '1.2.3',
  modules: '11',
  openssl: '1.0.1e',
  npm: '1.3.11' }
```

When I run

```
npm install fibers@1.0.1
```

I get

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fibers
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fibers

> fibers@1.0.1 install /Users/nbenes/node_modules/fibers
> node ./build.js

  CXX(target) Debug/obj.target/fibers/src/fibers.o
  CXX(target) Debug/obj.target/fibers/src/coroutine.o
  CC(target) Debug/obj.target/fibers/src/libcoro/coro.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Debug/fibers.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Debug/fibers.node: Finished
Build succeeded but target not found
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I get similar errors without the @1.0.1 and with a '-g' flag.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Try removing `~/.node-gyp` and try again. You could also use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) for installing and managing multiple versions of [tag:node.js].

Comment: Or use the [official installer for OS X](http://nodejs.org/download/) to see if that works (it does for me).

Comment: @robertklep: That's what I ended up doing -- post it as the answer and I'll tag it. Sorry for the delay. @fardjad: I think nvm is the right answer long term, and I'll be moving to that; removing `~/.node-gyp` is a good tip. Pretty sure my XCode was up to date at the time.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you need to upgrade XCode. This fixed it for me (as suggested in this StackOverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19648422/26510)

Comment: Good idea, but I had already upgraded it when I tried this.  Worth checking for those who haven't, though.