# Command line install of topojson throwing fatal error

Tags: node.js, topojson

I'm trying to install topojson on OSX Maverick and I'm getting a fatal error: `fatal error: 'sys/types.h' file not found`. I include below what leads up to the error in the terminal and then everything that follows.

I just installed node.js specifically for this - so I'm not sure which package the issue is related to.

```
...
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/boom
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/hoek
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream/0.0.5
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/contextify/src/contextify.o
In file included from ../src/contextify.cc:1:
In file included from /Users/anekola/.node-gyp/0.10.21/src/node.h:61:
/Users/anekola/.node-gyp/0.10.21/deps/uv/include/uv.h:59:10: fatal error: 'sys/types.h' file not found
#include <sys/types.h> /* size_t */
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/contextify/src/contextify.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/topojson/node_modules/d3/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.21
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.10
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I did use sudo: `sudo npm install -g topojson`. I am by no means an expert at command line.

Comment: Do you have xcode installed and upgraded to the latest version, and do you have the command line tools for xcode installed?

Comment: xcode may have been the issue. My office has some software on here that didn't react well to Mavericks, so things got screwed up. Updating that now - will update when I have results.

Comment: did you manage to solve this? I am getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

Jeff was right - thanks Jeff - seems like I just needed to make sure my xcode was updated. Actually, I discovered that I needed to reinstall xcode after I updated to Maverick. I didn't expect that.

Download link here: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/

Sorry, tak3r - thought I had posted this last week!